# PipeTransform is not working ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, pipe, ionic2

and I have some item to change words

> example : lang->language

I want to ion-option to show all items with the first letter in uppercase

> example : author->Author

example

```
author        Author
lang          Language
date          Date
loca          Location
```

mycode

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn(item, i);" >
        <ion-option [value]="item"  *ngFor="let item of totalfilter | mypipe;let i = index" >{{item["@NAME"]}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

mypipe.ts

```
       import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'mypipe', pure: false
    })
    export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public posts;
public post;
      transform(items: any[]): any[] {
          if (items && items.length)
            this.posts = items.filter(it => it["@NAME"] =  it["@NAME"].replace('lang','language'));
            this.post = this.posts.filter(it => it["@NAME"] = it["@NAME"].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ it["@NAME"].slice(1))

          return this.post;
        }

    }
```

is not working and error is

> Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Can you try like this ,Let item of (totalfilter | mypipe).Also did you register your pipe in app module

Comment: it still error , and yes I registered in app module > `import {MyPipe} from '../providers/mypipe';` and declarations add `MyPipe` , Where else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'mypipe', pure: false
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[]): any[] {
        if (items && items.length)
          return items.filter(it => it["@NAME"] = it["@NAME"].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + it["@NAME"].slice(1));
        return items;  
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you , I got it. I have new question! I want to add `it["@NAME"].replace('lang','Language')` How to add this and I try `return items.filter(it => it["@NAME"] =it["@NAME"].replace('lang','Language') && it["@NAME"].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ it["@NAME"].slice(1));` this uppercase all item but item `lang` is not change to `Language` but this change `Lang`

Comment: filter the items array first, after.. you map that items. What happened here is you are doing both at the same time. You can't monitor the values you are achieving.

Comment: I want to uppercase all item and  change words some item. Can not do it?

Comment: `*ngFor="let item of totalfilter | mypipe | uppercase;let i = index"` Angular 2 already has a built in uppercase pipe